# Does RDS Instance Actually Exist within Subnet Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds

I accidentally had an RDS instance associated with a subnet group in the wrong tier of subnets. I then changed the subnet group to include the correct subnets. I expected the instance to have to re-create itself since it was in the wrong subnet. I was surprised when it didn't have to, and the new subnet rules seem to have worked fine.

This leads me to question if the instance actually exists with the subnets of the subnet group, as I can't see how it could change to entirely new subnets without re-deploying. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It sounds like you've done something that shouldn't be possible.  If true, you may now be in a somewhat precarious situation.  Use `dig` to find the IP of the RDS instance, which should tell you what subnet it's in.  Let us know what you found.  Also... are you Multi-AZ?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yep it is definitely still on the previous subnet, meaning the changes I made to it (which I did via terraform) are out of whack. Also, it is not Multi-AZ. Luckily I caught this before the database had anything of value in it, so it's not a big deal to simply whack it and spin up a new one. Definitely a bug though.

Comment: Well, you might find that it is showing reboot-pending, and that a reboot triggers the migration.  Or that any other modification triggers it to migrate.  Changing instance family (e.g. `t` to `m`), class (e.g. `m3` to `m4`), or type (e.g. `m3.large` to `m3.large`) might also do it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did look for a reboot-pending flag on it, and didn't see it. That's why I figured it was changed successfully. I didn't try the instance resizing though, which may have worked. I decided to just recreate everything from scratch since terraform made it easy